# Choosing coordinate system to base coordinates off of Meridian of Mexico?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, mexico

I am using a source that is very old and all of the latitude coordinates are based off the Meridian of Mexico.

How would I search for these on my map?

I am working in QGIS 3.0. Also here is a map using the same coordinate system:

[image]

Comment: It's hard to read even at full resolution, but it looks as if the zero degrees line passes slightly to the east of Cuidad Victoria and Mexico City, so I'm guessing the longitudes are relative to 99 degrees west. Do you have enough rep to post a second, zoomed-in portion, ideally showing a town either side of the zero degrees line? I can't make out any info on there giving the exact parameters and type of the projection.